# How to get a QuerySet with type of a ForeignKey attribute in Django

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a simple database model in Django that looks like:

```
class Employee(Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

class PrizeDraw(Model):
    winner = models.ForeignKey(
        Employee,
        null=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
    )
```

What I want now is a QuerySet of type `Employee` that contains all the winners of all PrizeDraws. I would have thought that to be fairly straightforward by something something like:

```
def get_queryset(self):
    return PrizeDraw.objects.exclude(winner__isnull=True).values('winner')
```

However, that doesn't actually return me what I want, instead it returns:

`<QuerySet [{'winner': (Employee1) }, {'winner': (Employee2) }, etc...]>`

Which makes sense according to the [`values()` documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#values) it returns a Dictionary of values. But this doesn't work for me in the rest of the code I need, so I want to select only the second (i.e. value) part of the key-value pair and return that as a QuerySet that just looks like `<QuerySet[Employee1, Employee2, etc...]>`.

How can I select the right value as to get that desired QuerySet?

Comment: Don't use `values(..)`: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/over-use-of-values.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter with:

```
Employee.objects.filter(prizedraw__isnull=False).distinct()
```

This will retrieve the `Employee`s for which there is *at least* one *related* `PrizeDraw` record.

Comment: Thanks @Willem, this seems to actually work or at least do something, but I'm very confused as to why and how this can even work. By the looks of it, this filters the Empoyee table on the property "prizedraw" but it doesn't have that property (cause the reference to Employee lives in PrizeDraw). Could you elaborate why this works?

Comment: @Yellow: if you make a `ForeignKey`, `OneToOneField`, or `ManyToManyField`, Django will add a relation in reverse. The `related_query_name` by default is the model name in lowercase, so `prizedraw` in this case.

Comment: That makes some sense, but still doesn't seem quite right: why isn't `winner` mentioned in your answer? According to my understanding, if we added a second file on `PrizeDraw` like `second_place = models.ForeignKey(Employee)`, I think that might break your solution, correct?
(In other words, you solution happens to work in this minimal working example, but might not be correct in the general case)

Comment: @Yellow: if there are two or more `ForeignKey`s to `Employee`, then Django will error on the fact that the `related_name`s and `related_query_name`s are the same, and then you will need to provide a value for these, so `second_place = models.ForeignKey(Employee, related_name='second_prizedraw', related_query_name='second_prizedraw')` for example.